# remove an object from array in mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem to delete objects from an array in a mongoose schema.
As I saw on mongodb documentation I'm using

```
User.updateMany({}, {
   $pull: { "events": req.params.id} 
});
```

but it doesn't work.  the schema contains:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
email:                  { type: String, required: true },
...
date:                   { type: Date, default: Date.now },
events:                 [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'events'}]
});
```

i tried to use

```
.then( events => { events.save() }
```

with this it works but of course i receive an error.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating multiple documents then you should user multi:true option as well.

```
 User.update({}, {
   $pull: { "events": req.params.id} 
}, {multi : true});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for replying, but still doesn't work.
I searched on internet and multi is required for multiple documents only with update(), but I'm using unpdateMany() which include multi option.